# What is unapply method in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

What is `unapply` method is Scala? How does it work?

I know pattern-matching in other languages such as OCaml, and usually you have very little control over it. Is Scala unique in providing `unapply` method, or are there other languages that provide a mechanism for controlling patter-matching?

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html) can help, especially the paper at the end.

Answer (score 3):

In  Scala `unapply` is also called extractor method, for example consider this

```
scala> object SomeInteger {
 | 
 |       def apply(someInt: Int): Int = someInt
 | 
 |       def unapply(someInt: Int): Option[Int] = if (someInt > 100) Some(someInt) else None
 |     }
 defined module SomeInteger

 scala> val someInteger1 = SomeInteger(200)
 someInteger1: Int = 200

 scala>     val someInteger2 = SomeInteger(0)
 someInteger2: Int = 0

 scala> someInteger1 match {
      |       case SomeInteger(n) => println(n) 
      |     }
 200

 scala> someInteger2 match {
      |       case SomeInteger(n) => println(n)
      |       case _ => println("default") 
      |     }
 default
```

As you can see the second match prints `default` because the unapply method of `SomeInteger` returns a `None` instead of a `SomeInteger(n)`.

Other examples of extractors can easily be found for lists for example:

```
List(1,2,3,4) match { 
  case head :: tail => doSomething()
  case first :: second :: tail => doSomethingElse
  case Nil => endOfList()
}
```

This is possible because of how the `unapply` method is defined.